# Quantum Mechanisms for Isotope Fractionation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, bosons, isotopes

Are there any quantum properties that would enable isotope fractionation?

For example, atoms with odd versus even numbers of neutrons are fermions and bosons, respectively. Has any work been done using the distinct properties of fermions and bosons to isolate isotopes?

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure this relates to bosons, fermions, etc., there is a method only predictable using quantum mechanics.

There exists a method called "quantum sieving," where the zero-point energy difference between isotopes is exploited [2].

Since zero-point energy is inversely proportional to the de Broglie wavelength and mass of an atom, larger isotopes would have lower zero-point energy, and vice versa [2].

For context, the de Broglie wavelength is defined as:

> λ≈d–σ

Where "d" is the pore size of some metal-organic framework (MOF) and sigma is the molecular size of the isotope [2].

The zero-point energy is then proportional to

> 1 / mλ

Where "m" is mass and λ is the de Broglie wavelength.

For more information, the following papers will help immensely. I am a mere university undergraduate and there are many aspects of this technology I do not understand.

[1]: J. J. M. Beenakker, V. D. Borman, S. Y. Krylov,Chem. Phys. Lett.1995,232,379–382.

[2]: Oh, H. and Hirscher, M. (2016), Quantum Sieving for Separation of Hydrogen Isotopes Using MOFs. Eur. J. Inorg. Chem., 2016: 4278-4289. https://doi.org/10.1002/ejic.201600253

But yes, to answer your original question, there are quantum properties, the zero-point energy, that can be used for isotope fractionation.